# Issues with symmetry, possibly Origin?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, origin, remesh

Doing a sculpture of a face, I'm having issues with the symmetry tool, I've been trying to mirror the left side of the face to match the right side. But every time I do it merges the face weirdly in the middle and cuts out the nose.
[image]
[image]

I think that it might be an issue with the origin, but I've reset it using the 3D curser, and setting origin to geometry, but neither work.

I also tried using the mirror modifier and that yields the same results.

Comment: Also maybe apply the rotation of your object?

Comment: That fixed it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your object is not aligned with the global orientation, so it doesn't symmetrize as expected. Just apply its rotation.